# Is there a better way of obtaining the same output as table(vec) where vec is a vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector and I don't know, apriori, its unique elements (here: 1 and 2).

```
vec <-
  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

I was interested in knowing is there a better way (or elegant way) of getting the number of unique elements in `vec` i.e. the same result as `table(vec)`. It doesn't matter if its a data.frame or a named vector.

```
R> table(vec)
vec
1 2 
3 4
```

*Reason:* I was curious to know if there is a better way. Also, I noticed that there is a `for` loop in the `base` implementation (in addition to .C call). I don't know if it's a big concern, but when I do something like

```
R> table(rep(1:1000,100000))
```

R takes really long time. I am sure it's because of the huge number 100000. But is there a way of making it faster?

**EDIT** This also does a good job in addition to `Chase's` answer.

```
R> rle(sort(sampData))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an interesting problem - I'm curious to see other thoughts on this. Looking at the source for `table()` reveals that it builds off of `tabulate()`. `tabulate()` has a few quirks apparently, namely that it only deals with positive integers and returns an integer vector without names. We can use `unique()` on our vector to apply the `names()`. If you need to tabulate zero or negative values, I guess going back and reviewing `table()` would be necessary as `tabulate()` doesn't seem to do that per the examples on the help page.

```
table2 <- function(data) {
    x <- tabulate(data)
    y <- sort(unique(data))
    names(x) <- y
    return(x)   
    }
```

And a quick test:

```
> set.seed(42)
> sampData <- sample(1:5, 10000000, TRUE, prob = c(.3,.25, .2, .15, .1))
> 
> system.time(table(sampData))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.869   0.669   5.503 
> system.time(table2(sampData))
 user  system elapsed 
0.410   0.200   0.605
> 
> table(sampData)
sampData
      1       2       3       4       5 
2999200 2500232 1998652 1500396 1001520 
> table2(sampData)
      1       2       3       4       5 
2999200 2500232 1998652 1500396 1001520
```

EDIT: I just realized there is a `count()` function in `plyr` which is another alternative to `table()`. In the test above, it performs better than `table()`, and slightly worse than the hack-job solution I put together:

```
library(plyr)
 system.time(count(sampData))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.620   0.870   2.483
```

Comment: thanks good solution. Actually, I was also thinking along the same lines. I was curious if there is a solution using lapply or (for my liking) using plyr's functions (summarize,etc). (I know lapply won't necessarily improve the speed)

Comment: @suncoolsu - Have you seen `count()` from `plyr`? I wasn't aware of it previously, but your comment turned me down a path to finding it. Could be another viable alternative for you.

Comment: Well, `sort` inside `unique` is redundant; removing it gives me 3x speedup of `table2` on this data.

Comment: @mbq - you are right, we can `sort` outside `unique`. We do need sort though as `unique` would return `5 1 4 3 2` for this data so would not give the right results without sorting them...though it's obviously much cheaper to sort 5 values vis a vis 1M values. Nice catch.

Comment: good point that it is indeed required for integers; for factors, you just have to copy `levels` to the output of `tabulate`.